# Write a function to calculate a variable with a sequence parameter and summation

Tags: r, function

I need to write a function that calculates a variable for a sequence of inputs and a summation. I am writing this function because later on, I would be applying it to a dataframe.

The new variable `R` is calculated from the following equation:

[image]

In this equation `N_b`, `X_ext`, and the `sum.sqr.x` terms are constant numbers. `N_l` is a vector ranging from 1 to 5 and `m` depends on `N_l` as shown in the dataframe below:

```
> Multi.Presence
   N_l    m
1    1 1.20
2    2 1.00
3    3 0.85
4    4 0.65
5    5 0.65
```

There are 5 `e` terms (`e_1`, `e_2`, `e_3`, `e_4`, `e_5`). Depending on what `N_l` is, the summation term for e (`sum.e`) would add that many of the `e` terms. For example, if `e_1 = 14`, `e_2 = 18`,`e_3 = 7`,`e_4 = -6`,`e_5 = -11`. Then when R is calculated for `N_l = 1`, then the `sum.e` term is equal to `e_1 = 14`. When Then when R is calculated for `N_l = 2`, then the `sum.e` term is equal to `e_1 + e_2 = 14 + 18`, and so on.

I would like to write a function that calculates R for all values of `N_L` (from 1 to 5) and selects the maximum value of `R` and returns which `N_l` value resulted in the maximum `R` value.

```
> head (DATA)
  N_b N_l X_ext    x.sqr_sum   e_1    e_2    e_3   e_4    e_5
1   5   3    18       810      14.6   2.6   -9.4    0      0
2   5   3    18       810      14.6   2.6   -9.4    0      0
3   5   4    24       1440     21.8   9.8   -2.2  -14.2    0
4   5   4    24       1440     21.8   9.8   -2.2  -14.2    0
5   5   5    30       2250      29    17      5    -7     -19
6   5   5    30       2250      29    17      5    -7     -19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can be written in R as

```
func <- function(N_l, e, N_b, X_ext, sum.sqr.x)
{
  (c(1.2, 1, 0.85, 0.65, 0.65)[N_l] * N_l)/N_b + sum(e[1:N_l]) * X_ext/sum.sqr.x
}
```

However, this only allows for scalar values of `N_l`, so we want a vectorised version that will allow us to check all values of `N_l` at once. We will also allow this to have default values for the constants `N_b`, `X_ext` and `sum.sqr.x`. I have no idea what these are supposed to be, so I have defaulted them all to 1 here:

```
vecfunc <- function(N_1s, e, N_b = 1, X_ext = 1, sum.sqr.x = 1) {
  sapply(N_1s, func, e = e, N_b = N_b, X_ext = X_ext, sum.sqr.x = sum.sqr.x)
}
```

Now if we take the vector `e` from your example, we can plug in the values 1:5 to see how `N_l` changes the output:

```
e <- c(14, 18, 7, -6, -11)
vecfunc(1:5, e)
#> [1] 15.20 34.00 41.55 35.60 25.25
```

Note that this is with all the constants set to 1 and you will obviously need to change these to suit.

---

**EDIT**

With the new information from the OP, we can apply `func` to the data frame in an `sapply` like this to calculate R for each row of the data frame:

```r
R <- sapply(seq(nrow(DATA)), function(i)
{
    with(DATA, func(N_l[i], DATA[i, 5:9], N_b[i], X_ext[i], x.sqr_sum[i]))
})

R
#> [1] 0.6833333 0.6833333 0.7733333 0.7733333 0.9833333 0.9833333
```

Comment: Thank you so much Allan! This is exactly where I need to go. I just was wondering if you can help with the application of it. The `N_b`, `X_ext`, and `sum.sqr.x` are actually columns of a data frame with `N_l` and the `e_` terms. I have updated my original post to include the dataframe. I would like to implement this function to calculate `R` for each row of the dataframe, for all terms of vectorized `N_l` ranging from  1 to the value of `N_l` in the column of dataframe.

Comment: As you can see the `e_` terms exceeding the number in the `N_l` column are already see to zero in the code so the summation term can always be all the `e_` terms added together. The most important thing is calculating `R` for all values of `N_l` with the correct `m` factor that you included as a multiplied vector. I need to know which `N_l` term in the vector was responsible for the maximum value of `R` selected in the function.

Comment: @MaralDorri I think I understand. Please see my update.